# duplicate datetime from pivot_wider in r (dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr

**EDIT:**

**For reference, the below problem was a consequence of an internal function fault (see latest comment) not a generic issue with pivot_wider or datetime formatting as discussed below.**

**Original Post:**

Currently trying to understand why I might be getting the following issue, if you could help it would be greatly appreciated:

**Task:**

Have a dataframe that looks as follows:

[image: Original dataframe]

And I'm looking to pivot_wider utilising:

```
pivot_wider(names_from = 'tag', values_from = 'value')
```

**Result - I achieve this:**

[image: Resulting data frame]

Desired Outcome - when what I want is this:

[image]

And I can't understand why pivot_wider does not collapse by a common datetime?

My original thinking is that the formating of the datime may contain milliseconds in the actual format but not displayed visually in this table.

Any ideas anyone please?

Regards

**Edit:**

Reproducible example:

Based on code posted by 'deschen':

```
df <- data.frame(equipment = "EQUIP1",
                 datetime  = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4),
                 value     = c(NA, NA, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10),
                 tag       = c('speed', 'temperature', 'pressure', 'speed', 'temperature', 'pressure', 'speed', 'temperature', 'pressure', 'speed', 'temperature', 'pressure'))
```

Comment: You're probably right about the millisecond times. Try `df$datetime <- lubridate::floor_date(df$datetime)` (obviously substituting `df` for whatever your data frame is called), and trying again.

Comment: Can you share some dummy data for us to view?

Also in your raw dataframe the value=18.8 ,EQUIP1,VARIABLE 3 is for datetime=01/01/2020 00:00:00 while your expected outcome shows it for datetime =01/01/2020 00:00:01

Comment: `pivot_wider` will create new columns VARIABLE1 to VARIABLE3 using values of the original column `value`. The column datatime is not touched here. The column value is of class double, thus the variable columns are of class double as well.

Comment: Please provide an example of your data with `dput(YOUR DATA)`

Comment: Pleae check your updated example. E.g the tag variable won‘t work that way. It needs to be wrapped into c(…) and in quotation marks. If you can‘t share your real data, please tey to get as close as possible. This could also be done by simply changing a few values go your real data and then share this „faked“ version.

Comment: yes, apologies.  Ammended now.  This works as a sufficient example.  Just to note again.... the variable (tag) names could easily be flow_4, UV1, Speed-A, etc

Comment: The example still doesn‘t work, i.e tag has only 10 values, but should be 12 and a clsing bracket is missing.

Comment: Also, with the fixed example, the simple `pivot_wider(names_from = tag, values_from = value)` works fine for me.

Comment: Yes, I've just run a number of examples and it seems the original approach of pivot_wider is aggregating (on a simple example) - It would appear then that datetime being untouched is not the deciding factor.  I'm attempting to address the formatting, as per original discussions to see if this will work.

Comment: Are the four columns you've shown above the only columns in your data or was this just a snapshot? Also, I do understand that you can't share your full data, but since you already showed a screenshot of it above, you could at least share this part of the data with `dput(YOURDATA[1:10, c("equipment", "datetime", "value", "tag")])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been sometime since posting this up originally due to other commitments but wanted to share that the problem was in fact not with the pivot_wider or the datetime formatting but with another section of code within my function.

**Details:**

Within the function, prior to pivot_wider, I had created another feature (column) which was later 'de-selected' (removed) when preparing the table, post pivot_wider.

Consequently, pivot_wider recognised this row as unique but the column had later been removed - this caused the problem as described above.

**Solution:**

The 'de-select' of that column was moved to now be performed prior to pivot_wider - fixing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you do pivot_wider, but since datetime is still there and untouched, it will keep the number of rows. What you need is:

```
df <- data.frame(equipment = "EQUIP1",
                 datetime  = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4),
                 value     = c(NA, NA, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10),
                 tag       = rep(paste0("var", 1:3), 4))

df %>%
  group_by(datetime) %>%
  mutate(pivot_id = 1:n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-tag) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = pivot_id,
              names_prefix = "VARIABLE",
              values_from = value)
```

which gives:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  equipment datetime VARIABLE1 VARIABLE2 VARIABLE3
  <chr>        <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1 EQUIP1           1        NA        NA         1
2 EQUIP1           2         2         3         4
3 EQUIP1           3         5         6         7
4 EQUIP1           4         8         9        10
```

Note: Since you haven't provided a reproducible example of your own data, I had to construct it on my own.

Comment: Hi, thank you for this.  Unfortunately I can't post any original data but I will edit with a re-producible example.  I'm not sure if I can utilise the exact methodology above as the tag names need to remain.  I need to be able to pivot about those names - these names could be different at any point in time as the code is part of an 'ETL type' function with the user specifying what variable and equipment is to be pulled.  I will edit now using your reproducible example as a baseline.

Comment: This can probably be done dyynamically. Will check once you have provided your data example.